# How to create, start and exec a container without command run?

Tags: docker, command

To understando how to work the commands on docker, i tried create containers without the run command, but it dont work.
I create a container

```
$ docker create <image id>
```

so, i tried to start

```
$ docker start <container id>
```

and this return the container id. So, i exec this command

```
$ docker exec <container id> sh
```

what generate the error:

```
Error response from daemon: Container 985547c13d7e3434cc32c0c8bdb1b26fd76ebc95771bc55588866b170852e747 is not running
```

So, how to create a container and exec a shell to attach ( $ docker attach  ) without use run command? The create command seens useless if we cant start and exec on follow.

Comment: Could you please explain why you specifically don't want to use `docker run` to start the container?

Comment: `docker exec` isn’t part of the core Docker workflow.  The single command the container runs is a parameter to `docker create` and defaults to the image’s `CMD`.

Comment: @tobygriffin Because i thought it was possible to create a container and exec a command in a more "pure" and simple format.
For me its was logical that create a container, start and exec were 3 steps to use minimally a container.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do following steps

**create image**

```
docker create -t -i <image ID> /bin/bash
```

**start container interactive mode**

```
docker start -a -i <container ID>
```

Comment: But it works only with the '-a', '-t' and '-i' options. Without these options, 'create', 'start' and 'exec' are useless if you dont create a container with 'run' and more options, especially 'start'.